# Java function with "..." in parameter list from Scala

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions

As described [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Use-Java-function-with-quot-quot-in-parameter-list-from-Scala-td2251166.html)

If you want to make the code compile you have to add the `:_*` keyword to the `condition:Predicate`

Now I have this problem

```
val queryBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder()
     val cq = queryBuilder.createQuery(classOf[Product])
     val product:Root[Product] = cq.from(classOf[Product])
     val condition:Predicate = queryBuilder.equal(product.get("name"), "name")
     --> cq.where(condition:_*)


Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate required: Seq[?]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

You must not use `:_*` here.

There reason why `_*` exists is that varargs may lead to ambiguities.
In java If you have `f(int... values)` you may call `f(1, 2, 3)`, but also have do

```
int[] values = {1, 2, 3}; 
f(values)
```

With ints, it is ok. But if you have `f(object.. values)` and have `object[] values = {"a", "b"}`, when calling `f(values)`, should it means that f is called with a single arg, which is the `values`, or with multiple args `"a"` and `"b"`? (java chooses the later).

To avoid that, in scala, when there are varargs, it is not allowed to pass them as arrays (actually the more general `Seq` in scala) argument, except if you explicitly says you are doing so, by putting the abscription `:_*`.  With the previous example, `f(values)` means values is the single argument. `f(values: _*)` means each element of values, whether there are zero, one, or many, is an argument.

In your particular case, you are passing the `Predicate` arguments (actually just one) as separate (well...) predicates, not as a collection of predicates. So no :`_*`

**Edit**: I read the post you linked to more carefully. While what I certainly believe what I have written above is  true, it is probably not helpful. The proper answer was given by MxFr:

1. Since scala 2.9, interaction with java varargs is ok. just pass condition
2. Before that, you must pass your arguments as an array, and put :_*

Answer (score 4):

With Scala 2.9 `cq.where(condition)` should work, even `cq.where(condition1, condition2)` should work.

Alternatively you could use `cq.where(Array(condition):_*)`.

Comment: cq.where(Array(condition):_*) is what made it work for me in Scala 2.13

Answer (score 0):

I'm using scala library 2.9.0.1. This is the compiler error for that code, only passing the condition:

```
[ERROR]     D:\Mazi\Develop\workspaces\scala\sshwWebApp\src\main\scala\com\example\app\dao\DefaultProductDao.scala:54: error: ambiguous referenc
    e to overloaded definition,
    [INFO] both method where in trait CriteriaQuery of type (x$1: <repeated...>[javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate])javax.persistence.criteria
    .CriteriaQuery[com.example.app.domain.Product]
    [INFO] and  method where in trait CriteriaQuery of type (x$1: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression[java.lang.Boolean])javax.persistence.cri
    teria.CriteriaQuery[com.example.app.domain.Product]
    [INFO] match argument types (javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate)
    [INFO]      cq.where(condition)
    [INFO]         ^
```

Where is the problem?

If I use

```
cq.where(Array(condition):_*)
```

I receive the same compiler error:

```
[ERROR] D:\Mazi\Develop\workspaces\scala\sshwWebApp\src\main\scala\com\example\app\dao\DefaultProductDao.scala:54: error: ambiguous referenc
e to overloaded definition,
[INFO] both method where in trait CriteriaQuery of type (x$1: <repeated...>[javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate])javax.persistence.criteria
.CriteriaQuery[com.example.app.domain.Product]
[INFO] and  method where in trait CriteriaQuery of type (x$1: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression[java.lang.Boolean])javax.persistence.cri
teria.CriteriaQuery[com.example.app.domain.Product]
[INFO] match argument types (javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate)
[INFO]      cq.where(Array(condition):_*)
[INFO]         ^
```

Maybe the scala compiler that I use?

KInd regards
Massimo